# Código estranho (Verde) voltando do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, query

Tenho a seguinte consulta PHP

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

$mysqli-> set_charset("utf8");

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select header, title, footer, head from configs");

$stmt -> execute();

$stmt -> bind_result($header, $title, $footer, $head);

$stmt -> fetch();

echo $header;
```

Mas quando vou dar o `echo` no `$header` o código `<?=$teste?>` que está no banco de dados vem como uma exclamação e dois tracos antes da interrogação, fazendo com que o código não aparece, inspecionando consigo visualizar que a variável se encontra em verde. Porquê?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Se voce executar apenas o código que você nos informou, vai perceber que esse "codigo verde" (que se trata de um codigo comentado de PHP no meio do seu HTML, nao vai aparecer.

Recomendo que abra o codigo fonte dessa pagina que esta executando e procure por "" e vai descobrir que em algum momento você comentou esse trecho e se esqueceu!

Answer (score 0):

A cor não tem importância, é apenas o highlight para marcação das tags como o PHP faz.
Recomendo você trocar `<?=$teste?>` por `<?php echo $teste; ?>`

Você pode ver no link http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag, as 'tags curtas' nem sempre estão habilitadas.

Comment: Como a própria documentação diz, a partir do PHP 5.4 pode usar `<?=` sem medo de ser feliz, pois essa diretiva de configuração não o afeta.